# Is there a session time limit for sessions in host pool? in Azure

Tags: azure, session, azure-devops, virtual-machine

I'm trying to figure if we can find the time remaining for session termination when a user logged in to the host pool VM's. Also, is there a specific time limit for the host pool session( how long can they run if not specified.) If there happens to be a time limit, then what would be the maximum limit a user can be logged into the session.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal time out is 4 minutes, you can increase it up to 30 minutes.

Set time out when creating VM

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "mySvc" -Name "MyVM1" | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "HttpIn" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 8080 -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 15| Update-AzureVM
```

How to change idle timeout settings in Virtual Machines and cloud services. Thanks Joaoma post [Reference](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout.md#how-to-change-idle-timeout-settings-in-virtual-machines-and-cloud-services)